# My Site creation stuck at “We're almost ready!” in SharePoint 2013

Tags: mysite, single-sign-on

In our SP2013 on-premise farm, we have setup a web application to host My Site Host. Site self creation is activated.

All the users and service account are our test domain test.com accounts. However, our users are testing with desktop PC that joined the production domain company.com. They cannot login to SharePoint with single sign on. When they browse the SharePoint, it will prompt for password and user will type in test/accountID to login.

In this way, when they browse to the My Site page, the page always show "We're almost ready" message. The message is kept for days.

My question is:

1. Do I really need a single sign on user to login to My Site in order
   to activate it?
2. Any workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On our server there are 2 IPs. One for the main web application and one for the Mysite web application. The Mysite domain name was wrongly pointing to the main site IP. When users browse main site and mysite, since they are on the same server it looks no problem. However it caused the Mysite cannot be activated.

So to answer my question: we don't need a single sign on user to login My Site to activate it.

Comment: This is not generating the expected results on my mysite. For me this is happening with all of the new mysites that are being created. If I click on edit your profile I get an unexpected error that looks like an authorization eror.. I am the SCA on the site though so this does not make sense.

Comment: Do you mean all the MySites are being created before user first signon? Also please aware that each MySite is a SC. You are the SCA of some SC doesn't mean you control the MySite SC. By default each user is the SCA of their MySite.